# Настроить загрузку проекта по собственному url в angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular, angular-cli

Есть проект на `Angular 7.2.7`, при запуске `ng serve` он открывается по адресу `localhost:4200/some/path`. Однако возникла необходимость, чтобы проект открывался по адресу `my.favorite.url/some/path`, как этого добиться?

Текущая настройка в части `serve`:

```
   "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "cashier:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "cashier:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
```

UPD: у меня MacOs и правка etc/host не выход, так как в проекте трудится 30 человек, нужно сделать как-то так, чтобы у остальных просто подтянулись изменения из `master`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762125/set-default-host-and-port-for-ng-serve-in-config-file

Comment: @overthesanity если делать `ng serve --host foo.bar`, то мы получим вот такую ошибку `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND foo.bar`

Comment: потому что это делается просто так, там также можно найти описание что нужно редактировать файл `/etc/hosts` (на посикс системах)

Comment: у меня в проекте нет такого файла

Comment: это не файл проекта, почитайте что такое `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Есть [отличная статья](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) по этому вопросу

Comment: обновил вопрос, предложенные варианты в комментах не подходят

Answer (score 0):

Так, что бы после коммита в мастер у всех  все сразу обновилось: и гит спулился, и страница перезагрузилась, и конфликты автоматом разрулились, и фича сама имплементировалась... так не получится.

Есть варианты которми можно попробовать решить некоторые задачи, например

вместо `my.favorite.url` ставьте Ваш IP если `ng serve --host IP:8080`

таким образом, по идее, по Вашему ip в текущей сети можно заходить на Ваше приложение, которое запущено.

Вариант 2

Билдить приложение и использовать [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

```
npm run build
cd ./dist/PROJECT
http-server
```

Этот вариант подходит если нужно показать изменения после некоторой итерации. Например можно создать команду в `package.json`, которая будет стартовать сервер

```
ng build --prod && http-server ./dist/PROJECT"
```

Естественно изменения в гите не подтянутся.